# I can't understand a weird behavior, subclassing tablet widget

Tags: qooxdoo

Using qooxdoo 5.0.2 (or previous version) I subclass a tablet widget and override `_onKeyPress` method.
Then, generating source I get a correct behavior, but with generate build the behavior is different.

I simplified my question, with this example below.
I subclass table widget and override `_onKeyPress` method WITH THE SAME CODE from qooxdoo 5.0.2 table widget source.
Run the example, edit a cell, and press enter.

Using

```
var tbl = new qx.ui.table.TableModified(tableModel)
```

the behavior is bad.
Using

```
var tbl = new qx.ui.table.Table(tableModel)
```

the behavior is correct.

If you put the example in a blank 5.0.2 project, using `qx.ui.table.TableModified`, you get a behavior if compile source, and another with compile build.

What is wrong with this? Where is my error?

[Playground example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22qx.Class.define(%2522qx.ui.table.TableModified%2522%252C%250A%257B%250A%2509extend%2520%253A%2520qx.ui.table.Table%252C%250A%2509construct%2520%253A%2520function%2520(tableModel%252C%2520custom)%250A%2509%257B%250A%2509%2509this.base(arguments%252C%2520tableModel%252C%2520custom)%253B%250A%2509%257D%252C%250A%250A%2509members%2520%253A%250A%2509%257B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520_onKeyPress%2520%253A%2520function(evt)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(!this.getEnabled())%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520return%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520No%2520editing%2520mode%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520oldFocusedRow%2520%253D%2520this.__focusedRow%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520consumed%2520%253D%2520true%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520Handle%2520keys%2520that%2520are%2520independent%2520from%2520the%2520modifiers%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520identifier%2520%253D%2520evt.getKeyIdentifier()%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(this.isEditing())%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520Editing%2520mode%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(evt.getModifiers()%2520%253D%253D%25200)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520switch(identifier)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522Enter%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.stopEditing()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520oldFocusedRow%2520%253D%2520this.__focusedRow%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.moveFocusedCell(0%252C%25201)%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(this.__focusedRow%2520!%253D%2520oldFocusedRow)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520consumed%2520%253D%2520this.startEditing()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522Escape%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.cancelEditing()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.focus()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520default%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520consumed%2520%253D%2520false%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520else%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520No%2520editing%2520mode%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(evt.isCtrlPressed())%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520Handle%2520keys%2520that%2520depend%2520on%2520modifiers%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520consumed%2520%253D%2520true%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520switch(identifier)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522A%2522%253A%2520%252F%252F%2520Ctrl%2520%252B%2520A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520rowCount%2520%253D%2520this.getTableModel().getRowCount()%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(rowCount%2520%253E%25200)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(0%252C%2520rowCount%2520-%25201)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520default%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520consumed%2520%253D%2520false%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520else%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520Handle%2520keys%2520that%2520are%2520independent%2520from%2520the%2520modifiers%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520switch(identifier)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522Space%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__selectionManager.handleSelectKeyDown(this.__focusedRow%252C%2520evt)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522F2%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522Enter%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.startEditing()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520consumed%2520%253D%2520true%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522Home%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.setFocusedCell(this.__focusedCol%252C%25200%252C%2520true)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522End%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520rowCount%2520%253D%2520this.getTableModel().getRowCount()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.setFocusedCell(this.__focusedCol%252C%2520rowCount%2520-%25201%252C%2520true)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522Left%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.moveFocusedCell(-1%252C%25200)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522Right%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.moveFocusedCell(1%252C%25200)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522Up%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.moveFocusedCell(0%252C%2520-1)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522Down%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.moveFocusedCell(0%252C%25201)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522PageUp%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520case%2520%2522PageDown%2522%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520scroller%2520%253D%2520this.getPaneScroller(0)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520pane%2520%253D%2520scroller.getTablePane()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520rowHeight%2520%253D%2520this.getRowHeight()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520direction%2520%253D%2520(identifier%2520%253D%253D%2520%2522PageUp%2522)%2520%253F%2520-1%2520%253A%25201%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520rowCount%2520%253D%2520pane.getVisibleRowCount()%2520-%25201%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520scroller.setScrollY(scroller.getScrollY()%2520%252B%2520direction%2520*%2520rowCount%2520*%2520rowHeight)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.moveFocusedCell(0%252C%2520direction%2520*%2520rowCount)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520default%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520consumed%2520%253D%2520false%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(oldFocusedRow%2520!%253D%2520this.__focusedRow%2520%2526%2526%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.getRowFocusChangeModifiesSelection())%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520The%2520focus%2520moved%2520-%253E%2520Let%2520the%2520selection%2520manager%2520handle%2520this%2520event%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.__selectionManager.handleMoveKeyDown(this.__focusedRow%252C%2520evt)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(consumed)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520evt.preventDefault()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520evt.stopPropagation()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2509%257D%250A%257D)%253B%250A%250A%250A%250A%250A%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Document%2520is%2520the%2520application%2520root%250Avar%2520doc%2520%253D%2520this.getRoot()%253B%250A%250A%250A%2509var%2520tableModel%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.model.Simple()%253B%250A%2509tableModel.setColumns(%255B%2522Reparaci%25C3%25B3n%2522%252C%2520%2522Costo%2522%252C%2520%2522Cantidad%2522%252C%2520%2522Total%2522%255D%252C%2520%255B%2522reparacion%2522%252C%2520%2522costo%2522%252C%2520%2522cantidad%2522%252C%2520%2522total%2522%255D)%253B%250A%2509tableModel.setEditable(true)%253B%250A%250A%2509var%2520tbl%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.TableModified(tableModel)%253B%250A%2509%252F%252Fvar%2520tbl%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.Table(tableModel)%253B%250A%250A%250A%2509doc.add(tbl%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%252010%252C%2520top%253A%252010%257D)%253B%250A%2509%250A%2509%250A%2509var%2520a%2520%253D%2520%255B%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252001%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252002%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252003%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252004%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252005%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252006%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252007%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252008%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252009%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252010%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252011%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252012%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252013%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25200.0%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200.0%257D%250A%2509%255D%253B%250A%2509%250A%2509tableModel.setDataAsMapArray(a%252C%2520true)%253B%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In qooxdoo there are, per convention, protected and private class members like methods or instance variables. Protected members start with an underscore like `_myProtectedMethod`, private members start with two underscores like `__myPrivateMethod`. The protected members are not affected by the build process and left as they are. This way they are override-able by derived classes.

Private members are obfuscated by the compiler to a random name, so that trying to access the private method or variable outside the class where they are defined leads to an exception.

In your playground example you've overridden the method `_onKeyPress` which per se is OK to be overridden as it is a protected member.

But within the overridden code you're using private members like `this.__focusedRow` which fails, because in the build version there is no more `__focusedRow` member as it got obfuscated. There are more private members in the code like `__focusedCol`, `__selectionManager` etc.

To successfully override the method, you have to replace those private members  by their accessors, like `this.getFocusedRow()` instead of `this.__focusedRow`, `this.getFocusedColum()` instead of `this._focusedCol` etc.

Comment: thank you. I suspected it, I needed a confirmation because the source/build behavior thing confused me. Now is working ok. I do not know how this website works on answer qualifications, what I must do now. I'm going to read about.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept my answer if in SO if it answered your question. Thank you.